# DHCP server settings not loading

Tags: macos, osx-server

I’m trying to activate a DHCP server using Server.app but all I get is an empty window "Loading…" and a spinning wheel "Getting service state…" which spins forever. All other services seem to run without problems (except for the spinning wheel which somehow often does not stop spinning). How would I go about troubleshooting this problem?

[image: Server DHCP window]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Server.app messed up `/etc/bootpd.plist` by inserting a `</dict>` in the middle of the configuration.